# What is the difference between std::invoke and std::function?

Tags: c++, callable, c++17

Why do we need `std::invoke`, when we already have `std::function`? What is the difference between them? Both used to call callable objects. What's the point to add new template?

Comment: We already have a car.  Why do we need the color green?  (In short, in what way are those two things **similar**???)

Comment: `std::invoke` and `std::function` don't do the same thing at all

Comment: Watch this [cppcon 2015 talk by Stephan T. Lavavej](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zt7ThwVfap0)

Comment: @Yakk Maybe the point is that instead of holding a function pointer or member function pointer, you could hold an equivalent `std::function` and just call it directly.  So why would anyone need `std::invoke`?

Comment: That's like asking why we need `std::for_each` when we already have `std::vector`.

Comment: @TavianBarnes True, instead of painting a glass wall with green paint, you could park a car in front of it.  Both would block the light.  So both green and cars are opaque in the right circumstances...  And if the OP only thought of one application where opacity is all they need, I guess that could be the source of the question.  I still actually want a clarification from the OP.

Comment: @NathanOliver, thanks! The best comment!

Comment: @David, do the same, they both used to call callable objects in the end. Only in std::function we need to add brackets in the end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::invoke` is a generic way to activate *any* callable - a `std::function`, a pointer to function, a pointer to member function, a function object etc. Without having to know which one you are dealing with (and without having to use different syntax). It's mostly useful in generic programming (templates).

A standard function on the other hand is a generic container for a callable "thing". Not at all the same..